# Extract the version from filename

Tags: linux, text-processing, filenames

I want to extract the version number from the name of my build zip file.

build name: `build102p12.zip`

I want to extract `102p12` from this.

I am using linux enviornment: rhel 6.

Comment: Extracting from a zip file file does mean something different from extracting from a filename with suffix `.zip`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to remove the substrings `build` and `.zip` from the string `build102p12.zip`.

Assuming that you have the original string in a shell variable `name`:

```
name='build102p12.zip'

name="${name#build}"  # remove prefix "build"
name="${name%.zip}"   # remove suffix ".zip"
```

`$name` will now be the string `102p12`.

See the manual of your shell for further information about the `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter%word}` variable substitutions.

---

If you have the line (and nothing else)

```
build name : build102p12.zip
```

in the file `buildinfo`:

```
$ buildversion="$( grep -oE '[0-9]+p[0-9]+' buildinfo )"
```

The extended regular expression `[0-9]+p[0-9]+` will match anything that looks like `NNNpNNN` where each `NNN` is some sequence of digits.  This assumes that this only occurs *once* in the `buildinfo` file.

Comment: It's working, Perfect